# Unable to pass reference of GLWidget class in Qt

Tags: qt, opengl

I have a class called `MainWindow` and it initializes objects of `GLWidget` and `clothWidget` class, both  aforementioned classes inherit `QGLWidget` class. Initialization in `MainWindow` class is like

```
  glWidget = new GLWidget();
 clWidgetf = new clothWidget();
```

and I have an object of `GLWidget` class declared in `clothwidget.h`. When I do

```
clwidgetf->gl = glwidget ( here gl is object of class GLWidget declared in ClothWidget class) in MainWindow
```

I get following errors

> /usr/include/qt4/QtOpenGL/qgl.h:592: error: 'QGLWidget&
> QGLWidget::operator=(const QGLWidget&)' is private
>
> /home/arun/Desktop/garment/glwidget.h:8: error: within this context

Comment: You need to declare `GLWidget* gl` class member (it seems you've missed asterisk).

Comment: oh you are right I missed *, sorry for such a mistake, thanks for your guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are (unintentionally) trying to copy the widget, and since it is `QObject` based it cannot be copied. In the "olden days" (until very recently) the only way to make that was to make the copy constructor private, which is exactly the error message you are getting. Double-check your code to make sure you are not passing as a value copy (as Riateche suggested in the comments).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a reference then you have to initialize it with your object, you can not set it elsewhere, but most likely you want a pointer so you should pass pointer to your function and make your class member a pointer too, or take an adress of passet reference and still assign it to some pointer.

And you can't copy anything derived from QObject since constructors are private.